# Can you pull mongodb data by skipping out a level of data or grouping of data?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Consider you retrieve a dataset from MongoDB in this form.

```
a:{
    b:{
      d:x,
      e:y
    },
    c:{
      f:z,
      j:k
    }
}
```

could you rather query the data directly in this form?

```
a:{
  d:x,
  e:y,
  f:z,
  j:k
}
```

I understand that it can later be modified into that form after retrieving the entire thing. But I'm hoping that mongo can do that by itself faster, and be retrieving lesser data.

Comment: But this: [
      d:x,
      e:y
    ] is not a valid json object. is it?

Comment: That edit should sort it.

Comment: are the fields between b and c unique? ie can they have common field name